# What is the pull-back (in coordinates) of a Kaehler form under a projection map?

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-geometry

Let $X$ and $Y$ be complex manifolds such that $Y$ is a Kaehler manifold. Let $\omega= \frac{\sqrt{-1}}{2}\partial \bar \partial f$ be its associated (1,1) form of the metric on $Y$. Let $p: X \times Y \to Y$ be the projection map. How would one compute the pullback $p^{*}\omega$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is exactly the same. Namely, if $z_1, \cdots , z_n$ are coordinates of $X$ and $y_1, \cdots, y_m$ are coordinates of $Y$ the pullback of $\omega$ is formally the same thing both in the coordinates $z_1,\cdots,z_n,y_1, \cdots,y_m$ of the product manifold or in the coordinates $y_1,\cdots,y_m$ of $Y$.

This is so due to the following general way of computing pullback in coordinates: let $\omega$ be $2$-form on a manifold $B$ and let $f:A \to B$ be a smooth map. Let $p \in A$, $f(p) \in B$, $x_1,\cdots,x_n$ coordinates of $A$ around $p$ and $y_1,\cdots,y_m$ coordinates of $B$ around $f(p)$. So $f$ is given by formulae ${\bf x}:=(x_1,\cdots,x_n) \to (f_1({\bf x}), \cdots, f_m({\bf x}))$. Write $\omega$ as $$\omega = \sum_{ij} c_{ij}(y_1, \cdots, y_m) dy_i \wedge dy_j  $$
then the pullback $f^* \omega$ is $$f^*{\omega} = \sum_{ij} c_{ij}(f_1({\bf x}), \cdots, f_m({\bf x})) df_i \wedge df_j \, \,.$$

So if our map is $p(z_1,\cdots,z_n,y_1,\cdots,y_m) = (y_1,\cdots,y_m)$ and $$\omega = \sum_{ij} c_{ij}(y_1, \cdots, y_m) dy_i \wedge dy_j  $$ we get $$p^*\omega = \sum_{ij} c_{ij}(y_1, \cdots, y_m) dy_i \wedge dy_j$$
as I claimed above.

Comment: Thank you @Holonomia. But if one wanted to show this explicitly (in coordinates), how would one start the computation? For instance, $p^{*}\omega=\frac{\sqrt{-1}}{2}p^{*}\partial \bar \partial f = ??$